# How to use inner text of <a> tag to manipulate the directed page accordingly?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, local-storage

I have two HTML files: index and categories. On index.html, I've created the list of categories by using the javascript function and have added  tag to direct the user to the categories.html ( all links have the same href attribute). I want to change the content of the categories.html according to the inner text of clicked  tag on the previous page.

I used localStorage to store all category names but I don't know how to use those names to fetch accordingly on category.html when I don't know which  tag directed the user to the category.html. How can I detect the clicked link?

I'm sharing the element creation & localStorage code in case if the issue can be fixed in that code:

```
import { fetchData, createListItem} from "../Utils.js";
// List Categories
const createHeroCategories = () => fetchData("https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/categories.php")
  .then((data) => {
    data.categories.forEach((category) =>
      createListItem(".categories-list", category["strCategory"], "category-item")
    );
    Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('category-item')).forEach(element => {
        let temp = element.innerText;
        element.innerHTML = `<a href="./pages/categories.html">${temp}</a>`;
        localStorage.setItem(`${temp}`, temp);
    })
  })
  .catch((e) => alert(e.message));

export {createHeroCategories};
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved by adding onclick function that assigns the inner text to a single variable called "clickedItem". It will change the stored value, if another tag is clicked. I come up with this solution as "setItem" method can be used for changing/overwriting the old value of the same variable. The value will be stored when the user is on index.html, just before being directed to the categories.html.

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('category-item')).forEach(element => {
        let temp = element.innerText;
        element.innerHTML = `<a onclick="localStorage.setItem('clickedItem','${temp}');" 
                                 href="./pages/categories.html">${temp}</a>`;
    })
```

This way, "clickedItem" can be called on the categories.html, and used to fetch by using template literals like this:

```
 let clickedItem = localStorage.getItem("clickedItem")
 let API = `https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/filter.php?c=${clickedItem}`

 fetch(API).then(...).catch(...)
```